# C# How do I correctly return this collection?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to learn C# and I do not understand why I'm getting an error. I am getting the error `"ServerList.servers' is a 'property' but is used like a 'type'"`. I've read several guidelines that state I should not have a publically accessible list which is why I am trying to use a method to return the list of servers.

How do I correctly return the "servers" collection? Am I doing it totally wrong? Also, is there anything else wrong with my code?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        ServerList list = new ServerList();
        list.AddServer("server", "test1", "test2");
    }
}

public class ServerInformation
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string IPv4 { get; set; }
    public string IPv6 { get; set; }
}

public class ServerList
{
    private List<ServerInformation> servers { get; set; }

public ServerList()
{
    servers = new List<ServerInformation>;
}

    public void AddServer(string name, string ipv4, string ipv6)
    {
        servers.Add(new Server { Name = name, IPv4 = ipv4, IPv6 = ipv6 });  
    }

    public ReadOnlyCollection<servers> GetServers()
    {
        return servers;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's because `servers` is a property - `private List<ServerInformation> servers { get; set; }` - and not a type. Exactly what the error message is telling you. You need to return `ReadOnlyCollection<ServerInformation>` from `GetServers()` for it to work (although you won't be able to return `servers` as-is).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `ServerList` class has several problems.  I've included a comment for each one indicating what your code says and the corrected version below.

```
public class ServerList
{
    private List<ServerInformation> servers { get; set; }

    public ServerList()
    {
        //servers = new List<ServerInformation>;
        // constructor must include parentheses
        servers = new List<ServerInformation>(); 
    }

    public void AddServer(string name, string ipv4, string ipv6)
    {
        //servers.Add(new Server { Name = name, IPv4 = ipv4, IPv6 = ipv6 });
        // Server does not exist, but ServerInformation does
        servers.Add(new ServerInformation { Name = name, IPv4 = ipv4, IPv6 = ipv6 });  
    }

    //public ReadOnlyCollection<servers> GetServers()
    // The type is ServerInformation, not servers.
    public ReadOnlyCollection<ServerInformation> GetServers()
    {
        //return servers;
        // servers is not readonly
        return servers.AsReadOnly();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public ReadOnlyCollection<ServerInformation> GetServers()
{
    return new ReadOnlyCollection<ServerInformation>(servers);
}
```

You can't use a property as a generic type